# How To Use AFNetworking On Background Thread?

Tags: ios7, background-process, afnetworking-2

I have an app currently using AFNetworking 1.0 to sync data from a REST Web Service.

When the sync occurs currently by tapping a button on the UI it blocks the UI.

I'm upgrading the app to use AFNetworking 2.0.

How can I make the sync happen on a background thread so the UI does not stall?

Comment: No help with this yet?

Comment: please show your code

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gowalla.com/users/mattt.json"]];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@ %@", [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"first_name"], [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"last_name"]);
} failure:nil];
```

Check the following link
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Introduction-to-AFNetworking